# Kotlin Data Class from Json using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, kotlin, data-class

I have Java POJO class like this:

```
class Topic {
    @SerializedName("id")
    long id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
}
```

and I have a Kotlin data class Like this

```
 data class Topic(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

How to provide the `json key` to any variables of the `kotlin data class` like the `@SerializedName` annotation in java variables ?

Comment: How did you do it in Java? Show an example.

Comment: What's a json selector?

Comment: @voddan what I meant by those json selector is that strings that i can use to select particular json object / array : in my case "topic", "id","image" . I hope I made it clear to you. Thanks :)

Comment: @nhaarman I have edited the question, I hope that is what you mean

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Data class:

```
data class Topic(
  @SerializedName("id") val id: Long, 
  @SerializedName("name") val name: String, 
  @SerializedName("image") val image: String,
  @SerializedName("description") val description: String
)
```

to JSON:

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = gson.toJson(topic)
```

from JSON:

```
val json = getJson()
val topic = gson.fromJson(json, Topic::class.java)
```

Comment: Use annotations only when there's a variable name mismatch. Otherwise, yeah, not needed

Comment: In my opinion, the annotations allow us to have classes that when serialized can be excluded or include the variables. Very useful when used with retrofit. This does not send garbage to the server. Also, when there are changes in the names of the variables on the server side, it is more painful to change it directly in the class variable than in the annotation.

Comment: @Vik one thing to note is your variable names can possibly be obfuscated (like in an Android app) but the annotation will be left intact

Comment: @AntonGolovin I am not able to pass my data class in from Json method.Do I need to declare my data class inside java file?

Comment: If you do this, I believe you will lost JSON format which may cause IllegalStateException down the road

Answer (score 26):

### Based on answer of [Anton Golovin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118828/4488252)

### Details

- Gson version: 2.8.5
- Android Studio 3.1.4
- Kotlin version: 1.2.60

### Solution

> Create any class data and inherit **JSONConvertable** interface

```
interface JSONConvertable {
     fun toJSON(): String = Gson().toJson(this)
}

inline fun <reified T: JSONConvertable> String.toObject(): T = Gson().fromJson(this, T::class.java)
```

### Usage

**Data class**

```
data class User(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("authentication_token") val authenticationToken: String) : JSONConvertable
```

**From JSON**

```
val json = "..."
val object = json.toObject<User>()
```

**To JSON**

```
val json = object.toJSON()
```

Comment: Why do you use the `SerializedName` annotation instead of the field naming strategy, Vasily?

Comment: @Peter because `@SerializedName` will allow me to use custom names of the variables which may not match with json key. And yes, you may not use `@SerializedName` if you do not need it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use similar in Kotlin class

```
class InventoryMoveRequest {
    @SerializedName("userEntryStartDate")
    @Expose
    var userEntryStartDate: String? = null
    @SerializedName("userEntryEndDate")
    @Expose
    var userEntryEndDate: String? = null
    @SerializedName("location")
    @Expose
    var location: Location? = null
    @SerializedName("containers")
    @Expose
    var containers: Containers? = null
}
```

And also for nested class you can use same like if there is nested object. Just provide Serialize name for the Class.

```
@Entity(tableName = "location")
class Location {

    @SerializedName("rows")
    var rows: List<Row>? = null
    @SerializedName("totalRows")
    var totalRows: Long? = null

}
```

so if get response from the server each key will map with JOSN.

Alos, convert List to JSON:

```
val gson = Gson()
val json = gson.toJson(topic)
```

ndroid convert from JSON to Object:

```
val json = getJson()
val topic = gson.fromJson(json, Topic::class.java)
```