# Populating a Kotlin Data Class using Gson

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

I am attempting to populate a Kotlin data class from a corresponding string value.  I looked at: [Kotlin Data Class from Json using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117970/kotlin-data-class-from-json-using-gson) but what I am attempting to do is not tracking exactly the same:

```
fun convertStringToObject(stringValue: String?, clazz: Class<*>): Any? {
    return if (stringValue != null) {
        try {
            val gson = Gson()

            gson.fromJson<Any>(stringValue, clazz)
        }
        catch (exception: Exception) {
            // yes, we are swallowing the possible 
            // java.lang.IllegalStateException
            null
        }
    }
    else {
        null
    }
}
```

Calling this function and attempting to populate the following class:

```
data class LoggedUser(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("first_name") val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("last_name") val lastName: String,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String
)
```

It executes but LoggedUser values are empty (null).

The stringValue is currently:

```
{"nameValuePairs":{"id":"1654488452866661","name":"Bob Smith","email":"bob.smith@test.net","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Smith"}}
```

I even tried using a hardcoded class value like this:

```
gson.fromJson(stringValue, LoggedUser::class.java)
```

but there was no joy.  The **stringValue** is what **gson.toJson(value)** generated where **value** was a JSONObject.

Anybody have an idea what my disconnect is?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string actually has two JSON objects, the outer value (which has a key called `nameValuePairs`) and the value you actually want to deserialize (which is the value at key `nameValuePairs`). You need to dive one level deeper, either through an outer wrapper class which holds your User object or by manually getting the JsonObject at key `nameValuePairs` as a String and then passing that to Gson. If the string was just `{"id":"1654488452866661","name":"Bob Smith","email":"bob.smith@test.net","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Smith"}` it would deserialize fine.

Comment: Yes, as I understand it, I am running into the issue documented in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022133/how-can-i-delete-the-namevaluepairs-key-from-the-jsonobject ...  And unfortunately, I am stuck with working with JSONObject as opposed to JsonObject.

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper class

```
data class LoggedUserWrapper{
    @SerializedName("nameValuePairs") val nameValuePairs: LoggedUser
}
```

and execute

```
val loggedUser = convertStringToObject(yourJsonString, LoggedUserWrapper::class.java)
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it did not work.  I believe because nameValuePairs is not a JSON key but a member variable that is part of the JSON Object class.

Comment: Because nameValueParis is not a JSON key, identifying it as such (with SerializedName) means that it is not found and results in an empty data class.