# Kotlin data class converted with GSON always returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I try to store a data class using GSON as JSON string. However, gson always returns null:

```kotlin
fun jsonTest() {
    data class ImageEntry(
        val id: Int,
        val type: String,
        val path: String)

    val images = mutableListOf<ImageEntry>()
    images.add(ImageEntry(0, "test", "test"))
    Log.d("EXPORT_TEST", "$images")

    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(images)
    Log.d("EXPORT_TEST", jsonString)
}
```

This returns

```
D/EXPORT_TEST: [ImageEntry(id=0, type=test, path=test)]
D/EXPORT_TEST: [null]
```

I tried using `@SerializedName` from here ([Kotlin Data Class from Json using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117970/kotlin-data-class-from-json-using-gson)) but same result.

gson 2.8.7
kotlin 1.5.10

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the true "root" cause here, but this is happening because your `ImageEntry` class definition is local to the `jsonTest()` function. Move the class definition outside of the function:

```
data class ImageEntry(
    val id: Int,
    val type: String,
    val path: String
)

fun jsonTest() {
    val images = mutableListOf<ImageEntry>()
    images.add(ImageEntry(0, "test", "test"))
    Log.d("EXPORT_TEST", "$images")

    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(images)
    Log.d("EXPORT_TEST", jsonString)
}
```

When I run this, the output appears as expected:

```
D/EXPORT_TEST: [{"id":0,"type":"test","path":"test"}]
```